# PHP multidimensional array keep same keys with values

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to check a multidimensional array and keep only the keys they are match and has values (not same value).

So i want to check the whole array and get back the key's they have value, check them in all arrays and only keep the key's that all arrays contains.

So here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [tstamp] => 1508482179
            [firstname] => test1
            [lastname] => test1
            [dateOfBirth] => 
            [gender] => 
            [company] => 
            [street] => 
            [postal] => 
            [city] => 
            [state] => 
            [country] => 
            [phone] => 
            [mobile] => 
            [fax] => 
            [email] => test1@test.com
            [website] => 
            [language] => 
            [groups] => a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}
            [login] => 1
            [username] => test2
            [assignDir] => 
            [homeDir] => 
            [disable] => 
            [start] => 
            [stop] => 
            [dateAdded] => 1508482142
            [lastLogin] => 0
            [currentLogin] => 0
            [loginCount] => 3
            [locked] => 0
            [session] => 
            [createdOn] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [tstamp] => 1508482189
            [firstname] => test2
            [lastname] => test2
            [dateOfBirth] => 
            [gender] => 
            [company] => 
            [street] => 
            [postal] => 
            [city] => 
            [state] => 
            [country] => 
            [phone] => 
            [mobile] => 
            [fax] => 
            [email] => test2@test.com
            [website] => 
            [language] => 
            [groups] => a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}
            [login] => 1
            [username] => test2
            [assignDir] => 
            [homeDir] => 
            [disable] => 
            [start] => 
            [stop] => 
            [dateAdded] => 1508482142
            [lastLogin] => 0
            [currentLogin] => 0
            [loginCount] => 3
            [locked] => 0
            [session] => 
            [createdOn] => 0
        )

)
```

Code:

```
$arrResultMap = array_map('array_filter', $arrResult);
$currencies = count($arrResultMap) > 1 ? call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arrResultMap) : array_shift($arrResultMap);
print_r($currencies);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [groups] => a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}
    [login] => 1
    [loginCount] => 3
)
```

As you see there are some key's missing. Like email, firstname, lastname, tstamp, etc. I can't see or find what i have done wrong :)

***UPDATE:***
Found solution instead of using array_intersect i use array_intersect_key.
Now it works.

This code work:

```
$arrResultMap = array_map('array_filter', $arrResult);
$currencies = count($arrResultMap) > 1 ? call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key', $arrResultMap) : array_shift($arrResultMap);
print_r($currencies);
```